# Not let user enter alphabetic characters in a textbox

Tags: javascript

I need to validate a textbox which can only takes numbers. So i'm using the code below. It passes a message to the user but it also writes the alphabet to the textbox. I don't want anything written when user enters an alphabet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function numeralsOnly(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
    var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode : 
        ((evt.which) ? evt.which : 0));
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        alert("This field can only contain numbers.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [HTML5 input type number](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html) to restrict  only numbers:

```
<input type="number" name="someid" />
```

or

```
function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}

<input type="someid" name="number" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"/>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vKzAZ/)**</kbd>

Comment: i don't have HTML5. I want to alter the above coding to match the requirement. Now what?

Comment: I mentioned both ways hmtl5 and normal javascript code you can use anyone.

Comment: Did you add `onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"` to your HTML input tag like @Unknown mentioned? In your case, `onkeypress="return numeralsOnly(event)"`.

Comment: Yeah, its working there but not on my system. And yes I've called the function.

Comment: Make sure that you are calling same function that you mentioned in html and check whether function is invoked onkeypress.

Answer (score 1):

you use HTML5 's **input type = number**

```
<input type="number" max="100" min="1" steps="any"/>
```

There is javascript plugin availble [JqueryAlphanumeric](http://www.shiguenori.com/material/alphanumeric/)

```
$("#MytextBoxId").numeric(); // this will allow user to enter numbers only.
```